# X,Y random variables joint pdf

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that have joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Why would the pdf of $X+Y$ be $f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)dx$. I dont see why this is true. Would this also be true if $X$ and $Y$ were independent, I think that the pdf of $X+Y$ would also be this but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is true:

For any given $z$, the probability that $X+Y=z$ is precisely the probability that $X=x$ for ANY value $x$, and that $Y=z-x$. This is precisely the meaning of the integral given: you "sum up" over all $x$s, the density of the event $\{X=x,Y=z-x\}$.

In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, this statement is still definitely true; however, you can say better!  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then you can write
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)
$$
where $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are the (separate) densities for $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  As such, you can write
$$
f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,dx.
$$
This is called the *convolution* of $X$ and $Y$.